# Working on android studio app for call anouncer

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently working on call announcer for android
My code works perfect on some devices but it do not work on some devices
Following is my code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            String number=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Number:"+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

the number is toasted on some devices but not all devices

Main Activity

```
package com.apcoms.smsandcallannouncer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apcoms.smsandcallannouncer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".PhoneCallListener">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post full code. Including register receiver code.

Comment: @makkhokher give details of  issue persisting with device name??

Comment: IT works fine on Samsung note 2 but not on galaxy j7 or android studio emulators

Comment: @makkhokher what error is coming there..log files u can share  ??

Comment: There is no error, the app just didn't work on some phones.

Comment: Do i need to ask permission from user to allow broadcast services?